# Domain Driven Design - Common Behaviour

Tags: domain-driven-design

Imagine in a DDD inspired system we got multiple bounded contexts, each having a variation of a 'Person' domain object.

How do we go about designing behaviour common to all of these different Person objects?

Do we duplicate that behaviour in each Person class or do we use something like a Domain Service? I'm a bit confused.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: You might want to rely on a Shared Kernel, but don't forget that reuse is coupling. A small amount of duplication can often be favorable over trying to eliminate it all.

Comment: If bounded context are distincts then don't be afraid and write the code twice.

Comment: Please share samples of the specific Persons.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Found this talk by Udi Dahan which talks about the over glorification of reuse and it's impact on Software quality (Increased coupling). I've made peach with duplicating in this case. https://vimeo.com/131757759

Answer (score 0):

Challenge that you have shared bounded contexts.  Don't fall into the incorrect crowd-think that separate bounded contexts are common and must therefore be everywhere.  People hear that they are important, and therefore I must have some!

In a domain model, there are ways to model things, people and places acting in different roles (contexts).  It's one of the most common problems in domain modeling.

A Person can be acting (participating) as a Customer, a Supplier, a TeamMember, a AwardRecipient and a SocialGroupMember.

An Airport gate could be a DepartureGate, ArrivalGate and perhaps at times an EmergencyGate.

A Product can be a ProductBeingSold, a ProductBeingReturned, a ProductUnderDevelopment.

All these are typically modeled in a single domain representing the problem under consideration.